# installing gcc 4.2.4

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, makefile

I want to install gcc 4.2.4 on a linux x86_64, intel cpu with 2 cores, in a not default path. 
I downloaded the code via svn and configured  from a build directory with

```
../gcc_424/configure --prefix=/scratch/user/local/gcc-424 --with-local-prefix=/scratch/user/local/include
```

then in the build directory

```
make
```

when I run

```
make install
```

I get the error

```
/bin/sh: line 3: cd: ./fixincludes: No such file or directory
```

I am a little bit lost with what I should do now, any help?

Comment: Presumably the fixincludes directory is missing in the source package. Does it compile without --prefix?

Comment: I am not root, I cannot compile without prefix

Comment: You should be able to make without prefix. You can't make install though. Maybe try a fakeroot environment?

Comment: gcc-4.2 is extremely old. Wny can't you use a recent GCC? FYI, GCC-4.7 is released just now. Compiling GCC may be painful to beginners... Why do you need such an old version?? The version for your distribution (hopefully GCC-4.6) is very probably much better and upward compatible with older versions... Why do you need 4.2???

Comment: well, maybe I am approaching the problem in the wrong way, I was actually trying to compile llvm, but I get some errors at 'make check-all' in clang and llvm, using gcc 4.4.6. In the llvm documentation they say that the compiling should work with gcc 4.2, but new versions could miscompile portions of the llvm. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: LLVM & Clang is packaged in several Linux distributions... Why don't you install the packages??? And I was able to compile a recent (post 3.0) LLVM with a recent 4.6 (and also succeeded with 4.7) GCC... So you should not lose your time with GCC 4.2

Comment: ok, I was just trying with a different version of gcc to see if there was any difference. Btw, what about if I just want to compile from the source??? Is it that difficult?? do you have any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Although untested (because it's fairly old), [EasyBuild](http://hpcugent.github.com/easybuild/) should be able to build GCC 4.2 without much trouble.
Just use one of the [available example easyconfigs](https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild/tree/master/easybuild/easyconfigs/g/GCC) for GCC (the non ClooG-PPL ones), adjust the version number, and run the EasyBuild install command specifying that easyconfig file.
No root priveleges required, and EasyBuild takes care of all the nasty stuff.